# Laravel beyondcode websockets - doesn't work if verify_peer is true

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

I'm using the package `beyondcode/laravel-websockets`.

My problem here is when I set the `'verify_peer' => true` the websocket is not working, but when the value is `false` it is working. Is there anyone here managed to make this to work?

For production website, I want set the `verify_peer` to `true` to prevent man-in-the-middle attack.

I have a website, lets say `aceraven777.com`, it already has `SSL` installed (in the `cPanel` it has `autoSSL` enabled).

In the websockets config I entered the same path (the one that `cPanel` generated) for the certificate and private key.

The chrome throws an error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://aceraven777.com:6001/app/asdfswerqwsafasfd?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false' failed: 
createWebSocket @ pusher.min.js:8
```

This is the error in firefox:

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://aceraven777.com:6001/app/asdfswerqwsafasfd?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false. pusher.min.js:8:6335
```

Below are the settings I used:

config/websockets.php

```
'ssl' => [
    /*
        * Path to local certificate file on filesystem. It must be a PEM encoded file which
        * contains your certificate and private key. It can optionally contain the
        * certificate chain of issuers. The private key also may be contained
        * in a separate file specified by local_pk.
        */
    'local_cert' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT', null),

    /*
        * Path to local private key file on filesystem in case of separate files for
        * certificate (local_cert) and private key.
        */
    'local_pk' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK', null),

    /*
        * Passphrase for your local_cert file.
        */
    'passphrase' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_PASSPHRASE', null),

    'verify_peer' => true,
],
```

config/broadcasting.php

```
'pusher' => [
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
        'host' => env('PUSHER_APP_HOST'),
        'port' => env('PUSHER_APP_PORT'),
        
        'useTLS' => true,
        'scheme' => 'https',
        
        'curl_options' => [
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 1,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 1,
        ],
    ],

    // Configuration for laravel mix JS
    'mix' => [
        'host' => env('MIX_PUSHER_APP_HOST'),
        'key' => env('MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'cluster' => env('MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
        'port' => env('MIX_PUSHER_APP_PORT'),
    ],
],
```

Comment: Hope this helps https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/187

Comment: @Haridarshan, mine is showing a different error: `WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:6001/app/asdfswerqwsafasfd?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false' failed`.

Comment: Can you please share complete Error response.

Comment: Also, You're getting this error in Chrome or Firefox as well?

Comment: @Haridarshan I edited my question, those are the complete error response in Chrome and firefox.

Comment: @aceraven777 .few issues from github https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/665
https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/187
https://alex.bouma.blog/posts/installing-laravel-websockets-on-forge-with-ssl/
https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/392
https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/513
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55076399/laravel-websocket-in-homestead-not-working/56370064#56370064
https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/116 .it might help you

Comment: @aceraven777 have you figured this one out? having the same problem here..

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify a Certificate Authority file on the local filesystem.

This is the source of 95% of these errors on production servers.

The other 4% are caused by self-signed certificates, which I doubt you have in a production environment.

You will need to modify your `config/websockets.php`

```
'ssl' => [
    // ... 

    'capath' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_CA', null),
],
```

The CA path typically a directory similar to `/etc/ssl/certs/`.

If this does not work try allowing self-signed certs:

```
'ssl' => [
    // ... 

    'allow_self_signed' => true,
],
```

For more information, you should look at the [PHP specification for SSL verify peer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php#context.ssl.verify-peer).

Comment: is `cafile` different from `local_cert` and `local_pk`?

Comment: Local cert is the CA file, but are you sure it's correct?

Comment: yes i'm sure. I contacted the support team and validated that the ca files, private keys are in the correct path. Its quite frustrating that I can't make this to work. I guess I have to make the `verify_peer` to false then

Comment: @aceraven777 I was incorrect, the CA cert is specified as `'capath' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_CA', null),` in the SSL configuration.

Comment: It doesn't matter if we use `cafile` or `capath` right? Base on the PHP documentation `cafile` is the full path to the CA file itself while `capath `is the directory where the CA file is located. As long as you point it to the right file/directory it should work right? I tried both `cafile` and `capath`, none is working :(

Answer (score -1):

This article helped me a lot some time ago implementing websockets especially with SSL certificate:
https://christoph-rumpel.com/2020/11/laravel-real-time-notifications

You also have git repositories telling you how to implement with and without SSL.

Comment: Do you remember in your `config/websockets.php` if you set `'verify_peer' => true`? That's my problem now, if I set this to `false` its working.

Answer (score -1):

To me it seems, you are not connecting to the correct port.

PusherJs uses default web ports 80 and 443, as described here: https://pusher.com/docs/channels/library_auth_reference/pusher-websockets-protocol

Change the port inside your .env file

Comment: I am using the correct port, if you completely read my question details, it is working if I set `verify_peer` to `false`. its not working if I set it to `true`

Comment: @aceraven777 Ok, are these files local_cert and local_pk readable? What are the permissions of these files? You can check if this is the issue with `php artisian websocket:serve`